# Convert multiple date formats stored as text

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-view

I have a column that is a date column that is stored as text.
This has three formats in it.

1. dd mmm yyyy
2. MM/dd/yyyy
3. yyyy-mm-dd

[image]

I need to convert all these to one format. Im hoping 112 (yyyymmdd)

can anyone help as I keep getting an out of range error.

I have got it to return this correctly

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), ISNULL(CAST(cf3.FieldValue as date),CAST('01/01/1900' as date)),101)
```

But I cant seem to then convert to yyyymmdd format without the range error.

Comment: Do you have any sample code/data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
01 Jan 1900
12/5/2013
2013-12-10
```

Query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, TestColumn), 112)
FROM tblTestTable
```

Output:

```
19000101
20131205
20131210
```

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of **`STR_TO_DATE`** with **`DATE_FORMAT`** to achieve desired results.

```
SELECT
IFNULL(
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(COL_NAME, '%d %b %Y'), '%Y%m%d'), 
  IFNULL(
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(COL_NAME, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y%m%d'),
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(COL_NAME, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y%m%d')
  )
) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

**`STR_TO_DATE`** will convert the string into a **datetime** datatype and then **`DATE_FORMAT`** will convert datetime into the desired format(**`'%Y%m%d'`** -> **`'yyyymmdd'`**).

Comment: This is SQL Server. There is no STR_TO_DATE Function. But this is handy Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @mydate datetime = '2017-03-20'

select RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(DD,@mydate) as nvarchar(max)),2) + ' ' + UPPER(CAST(DATENAME(month,@mydate) AS VARCHAR(3))) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @mydate) as nvarchar(MAX)) as 'dd mmm yyyy',
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(DD,@mydate) as nvarchar(max)),2) + '/' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @mydate) as nvarchar(Max)),2) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @mydate) as nvarchar(MAX)) as 'dd/mm/yyyy',
CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,@mydate) as nvarchar(max)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @mydate) as nvarchar(Max)),2) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(DD, @mydate) as nvarchar(MAX)),2) as 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

You can manually get the corresponding dateparts of the date and perform the formatting yourself. (if format needed is not readily available)

Comment: That works for one format which I had figured out but doesn't work for the other two.

Comment: @LucasPerrett what's the issue with the other formats? are you getting an error? incorrect format?